# Can't call kendo js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui

I have a source code to call kendo.all.min.js. When i try to call kendo.common.min.css and kendo.default.min.css. I don't get any error, but when i try to call kendo.all.min.js i get an error like this:

[image]

And i call kendo.all.min.js, the library call picture cstCorpTable.js also. But in the kendo library, i don't have cstCorpTable.jpg.

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

cstCorpTable.js is not part of kendo ui. That's the reason you can't find the jpg in the kendo library.
I don't know where you got the cstCorpTable.js from. I suggest you have a look at the original location and copy cstCorpTable.jpg from there. Not only cstCorpTable.js